# Fullscreen image inside a ViewFlipper

Tags: android, image, fullscreen, viewflipper

I have a ViewFlipper in my xml layout that contains an Image. I would like to display this image fullscreen. No matter which ScaleType I use for the image I can't get the image to display fullscreen.

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ViewFlipper android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/flipperView" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frameLayout1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/my_drawable" android:id="@+id/bcImageView" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="center" android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
        </FrameLayout>
    </ViewFlipper>     

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the code in my Activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Force landscape mode
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    // Hide window title and go fullscreen
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.flippertest);

    mViewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipperView);
    mViewFlipper.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    mViewFlipper.requestFocus();
    mViewFlipper.setOutAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
    mViewFlipper.setInAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
```

I've also tried using:

```
    mViewFlipper.setClipChildren(false);
    mViewFlipper.setMinimumHeight(300);
```

with various values of minimum height but nothing.

Any ideas why the image is not displayed fullscreen ?

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? having similar problem

Comment: nope, I redesigned completely the UI.

Comment: am considering the same thing!

Answer (score 4):

Try to set `yourImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);` This worked for me and solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change your ImageView's `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` in your layout